# binding bitmap image to a return stream from server after POST

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, bitmapimage

I do a normal POST method and server return a stream, which is a bitmap image, then I want to set my Image1 to that stream that I got:

```
        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        HttpStatusCode rcode = response.StatusCode;

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {
            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(stream);
            image1.Source = bi;
        });

        response.Close();
    }
```

This give an error: Can not access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream'.

I understand why I got this error, it's because the Stream response.Close(); and I use the Dispatcher. If I don't use Dispatcher it will give invalid-cross thread.
How do I set the stream to my image1?

Comment: What is your intention with the `stream?` You first use it as an XML string, and then try to use it as the source to a `BitmapImage`? Is this just made 'safe to post' on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a variable, which is avaliable both the callback and the UI thread?